# Celery pass arguments to subclass of Task?

Tags: python, celery

In the celery documentation: [instantiation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation)

We see a great example of using a base task to cache a database connection:

```py
from celery import Task

class DatabaseTask(Task):
    _db = None

    @property
    def db(self):
        if self._db is None:
            self._db = Database.connect()
        return self._db
```

This is great if `Database.connect()` is shared and does not require any parameters in this example.

However, if you were to go about passing some variable to the cached `db` prop, would that be possible? How could you do that? As an (obviously wrong) example:

```py
class DatabaseTask(Task):
    _db = None

    @property
    def db(self):
        if self._db is None:
            #Get calling task's some_id here
            self._db = Database.connect(some_id)
        return self._db
```

By somehow passing that either as an argument to the task:

```py
@task(base=DatabaseTask, bind=True)
def my_db_task(some_id):
   return self._db is None
```

or some other way?

EDIT:

The reason I'm asking is that I have a lot of tasks that are executed independently of another but all need a connection to a remote host:

```py
@task
def task_a(id, param2, param3, .. ):
   try:
       s = get_connection(db.query.get(id))
   except:
       raise TaskFailedException()
   # do other stuff
```

and it would be nice if other tasks (task_b, task_c) could share the `s` connection without having to reconnect for every request

Comment: Are you talking about sharing a settings object, or sharing the actual connection? The latter might be an issue, if they're separate processes, which I think is the point of celery, although I'm not sure.

Comment: Im talking about sharing a connection or an object representing a connection, in the same tay the top example shows how to initialize a connection to the database if there isn't one. Hope this clarifies things.